# Python to Arduino Delay

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, arduino-uno

I have a project where in an ultrasonic sensor outside of my room is detecting if someone is under 73cm away from it. Okay, it works, after that, an LCD will turn on and prompt the person outside if he wants to enter or not, 1 if yes, and 2 for no. If the person pressed 1, it will send a serial information to my python code that someone wants in. Now if someone wants in, a function for speech to text will execute and if the whole speech input contains a word that's the same with any of the words in the keywords array, it will send back an information over serial to the arduino and make the servo with a string attached to my door knob rotate. Now, the problem is once I the speech input was detected and checked for the keywords, it will send the information, but it won't make the servo rotate. However, once the whole thing loops again and the person pressed 1, the servo will rotate, but I haven't even started the voice command yet. It's like, the serial command after the speech to text function got stuck in the arduino side and the code just stopped. Thank you in advance, everyone!

Note: I've checked the wirings, the USB connection from my arduino to my PC, and it's all secured, and that's why I concluded it's because of the code.

Python code:

```
import time
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import threading
import speech_recognition as sr
import concurrent.futures
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

# Arduino stuff
com4 = serial.Serial(port="COM4", baudrate=9600)
keywords = ["sige lang", "buksan", "papasukin", "open"]
time.sleep(2)


# Functions
def speech_to_text():
    # Initialize recognizer
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    # Use microphone as source
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Speak Anything:")
        # Adjust for ambient noise
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        # Record the audio
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        # Recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        return text
    except:
        print("Sorry, could not recognize your voice")
        return ""


def show_notification(title, message):
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast(title, message, duration=3)


def arduino_connection():
    com_ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    arduino_connected = False
    for port, desc, hwid in sorted(com_ports):
        if 'USB VID:PID=1A86:7523' in hwid:
            arduino_connected = True
            break
    return arduino_connected


def wait_for_keypad_keypress():
    # with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    while True:
        person_outside = com4.readline().decode().strip()
        if person_outside == "Wants in":
            print("Wants in")
            show_notification("test", "Someone wants to go in, Romy!")
            speech = speech_to_text()
            if any(word in speech for word in keywords):
                byte_to_send = 65  # Example byte value
                com4.write(byte_to_send.to_bytes(1, 'big'))
                print("done")

# Logic
arduino_is_connected = arduino_connection()
if arduino_is_connected:
    print("connected")
    com4.write("Establish connection".encode())
    time.sleep(1)
    connection_established = com4.readline().decode().strip()
    print(connection_established)
    if connection_established:
        com4.write("Start detecting".encode())
        detecting_state = com4.readline().decode().strip()
        print(detecting_state)
        if detecting_state == "Detecting":
            wait_for_keypad_keypress()

# main_window = tkinter.Tk()
# main_window.withdraw()
# main_window.mainloop()
```

Arduino code:

```
#include <Key.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// Variables
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
const byte rows = 4;
const byte columns = 3;
char keys[rows][columns] = {
  { '1', '2', '3' },
  { '4', '5', '6' },
  { '7', '8', '9' },
  { '*', '0', '#' }
};
byte rowPins[rows] = { 8, 7, 6, 5 };
byte columnPins[columns] = { 4, 3, 2 };
const int trigPin = 11;
const int echoPin = 10;
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, columnPins, rows, columns);
Servo servo;
long duration = 0;
long distance = 0;
bool continueDetecting = false;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  Wire.begin();
  lcd.init();
  servo.attach(9);
}

bool connected = false;
void loop() {
  if (!connected) {
    String connectToPython = Serial.readString();
    if (connectToPython == "Establish connection") {
      connected = true;
      Serial.println("Connection established");
      String detectingState = Serial.readString();
      if (detectingState == "Start detecting") {
        Serial.println("Detecting");
        while (true) {
          digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(2);
          digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(10);
          digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
          duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
          distance = (duration / 2) * 0.0343;
          delay(500);
          if (distance <= 73) {
            lcd.clear();
            lcd.backlight();
            lcd.setCursor(1, 0);
            lcd.print("Wanna come in?");
            lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
            lcd.print("1 = Yes | 2 = No");
            unsigned long startTime = millis();
            char keyPress = NO_KEY;
            while (keyPress == NO_KEY && (millis() - startTime) < 5000) {
              keyPress = keypad.getKey();
              delay(50);
            }
            if (keyPress == '1') {
              Serial.println("Wants in");
              int receivedByte = Serial.read();
              String servoState = Serial.readString();
              if (receivedByte == 65) {
                spinDoorknob();
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void spinDoorknob() {
  servo.write(180);
  delay(1000);
  servo.write(0);
  delay(300);
  servo.write(90);
}
```

I tried adding delays for the serial reading, however, based on what I saw in other forums, the delays will just make things worse, and so I removed them. I tried to run the program, however, the same thing happened.

I also tried the newline after the serial information to be sent already.

I also always get this error:
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

After the notification from the win10Toast library disappears.